# Do we want to add a Twitter account?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Stack Exchange offers some amount of Twitter integration (for example see [@StackWorkplace](https://twitter.com/StackWorkplace)).

Do we want to add this to the Vi site?

---

*Update*: [It's been added](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1408/51).

Comment: When will the decision of getting an account (or not) will be taken? Also I know some other user already volunteered but if you guys need some help I'll gladly give a hand :-)

Comment: @statox I'll contact the SE team today and see what our options are.

Comment: Ok thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 10):

*Update*: I sent an email to the good folks at Stack Exchange, and this was their reply:

> Unfortunately Twitter does not actually allow bot-style Twitter accounts in
>   the fashion that we use them by default and they kept getting flagged and
>   blocked by their system. The process for getting them "pardoned" so to
>   speak is excessively annoying, so we do not create or integrate Twitter
>   accounts with new sites anymore. You're welcome to create your own Twitter
>   account for your site and use it, but just be aware that bot-like activity
>   is likely to get the account blocked on their service.

So that solves that :-)

I set up a preliminary account at https://twitter.com/ViStackExchange – more later.

---

I would say *yes*, but I would prefer *not* automatically posting with the Twitter bot. From [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183407/166789):

> [it is] set up to automatically tweet a new status every 3 hours. According to this answer by Nick Craver there is a "hotness" algorithm based on views over a certain period of time.

Personally, I'd much rather post a *single* high quality post every few days (or even weeks) rather than post mediocre (or bad) questions that just so happened to be the "hottest" one today.

This would mean people would have to manually curate and post stuff. This can be done by moderators and possibly some long-standing members of the community. We can work out the details of this later.

I'm not sure if it's possible to have the Twitter link appear in the [site overview](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and such *without* using the Twitter bot; this is something we'll have to ask the Stack Exchange team. Personally I wouldn't consider it that much of a loss, since the Twitter link doesn't seem to be prominently displayed anyway (can you discover that [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) has a Twitter account? I can't).

Comment: I think this sounds like an awesome idea. I'm all for it! It also makes sense for a smaller site like ours to be manually curated instead of posting automatically every three hours.

Comment: *If* we choose to have a twitter account I totally agree that it must not be automated (at least until we become a big mainstream site, which might never happen).

Comment: About the name, emacs has [emacsSE](https://twitter.com/EmacsSE) maybe something like `vi_vimSE` or `vi_vim_SE`;...

Comment: @statox went with "ViStackExchange" for now ... the whole "vi_vim" thing looks ugly IMHO, and "vi_se" was already taken.

Comment: Could we set [Nobe4's brilliant ASCII-vim logo](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/1299/2920) for the profile picture?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem But I spent so much time making the current logo!

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, do we want to do anything with existing twitter accounts on Vim?

- [vimtips](https://twitter.com/vimtips): 24k followers,
- [MasteringVim](https://twitter.com/MasteringVim): 10k,
- [VimLinks](https://twitter.com/VimLinks): 1k,
- ...

I've seen a few times those accounts sharing posts from stackoverflow/vi.stackexchange...

Could we imagine contacting them so they share some good quality posts?

Comment: `Could we imagine contacting them so they share some good quality posts?` -> I'm not sure why we should? I would assume they're just tweeting something they stumbled upon and found useful, rather than random posts.