# :set buftype=twitter

Tags: discussion

We're so hip we got ourselves a Twitter account: [@ViStackExchange](https://twitter.com/ViStackExchange).

We won't be posting questions automatically with a bot like the Twitter accounts of most other Stack Exchange sites do. Instead we'll be adding interesting questions or questions with interesting answers, which could be both old and new questions.

In other words: it should be a "best of", rather than "ZOMG STOP SPAMMING MY TWITTER INBOX!"

Follow it! Like it! Retweet it! Do whatever else people do on Twitter!

Comment: "Do whatever else people do on Twitter!"  In this context that would be posting loads of trolly nonsense about emacs!

Comment: What's the best way to submit suggestions of interesting Qs/As? @-mention the account on Twitter? A message in `:chat!`? An answer to this question?

Comment: @Rich A chat message is probably best since most people with access to the account see that. An answer would bump the question to the top, which wouldn't be so great.